# Can I add multiple answers for a single question in Azure QnA Maker?

Tags: azure, azure-qna-maker

I'd like to have users input a single prompt, like "read me a poem," and have QnA give a different response every time.  Ideally, QnA would rotate through a list of responses I've created.  Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I have the same question. I understand that you can use language generation in Bot Composer for example, but does qnamaker support LG definition or not?

Comment: @AlirezaManashty - It does not. You'd have to handle that on the bot side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not really the best use case for QnA maker.  QnA Maker enables you to power a question-and-answer service from your semi-structured content like FAQ documents, URLs, and product manuals. The QnA Maker service answers your users' natural language questions by matching it with the best possible answer from the QnAs in your Knowledge base.

What you are looking for can be done with a Chat Bot where you write the logic for rotating responses.  Visual Studio has a [echoBot sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-tutorial-basic-deploy?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp) pre-loaded that can help you get started and we have a good deal of documentation here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-dialog-manage-complex-conversation-flow?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp

Answer (score 2):

yes, you can now: they added the param "top" to the JSON object for the POST:

e.g.

```
{
  "question": "Hi",
  "top": 30,
  "isTest": true,
  "RankerType":"QuestionOnly"
}
```

POST to QnAMaker API returns (max.) the top 30 answers.

See also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/how-to/improve-knowledge-base#use-the-top-property-in-the-generateanswer-request-to-get-several-matching-answers

Comment: This answers the question of how to get multiple answers in a single call to the QnA Maker API, but those answers will be from different QnA pairs. Tyler S seems to be asking how to add alternate answers to a single QnA pair, in the same way that you can add alternate questions to a QnA pair.